# UI Automator displays elements of previous screen intermittently

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

We have one third party mobile application to automate and i'm facing below issues:

1)Login to the app,tap on any object which re-directs us to another screen. Here when i tap on object we will see screen loading with rotating icon,now once its navigated to other object page,when i'm trying to inspect elements in UI automator,its returning dumps of previous screen i.e loading rotating bar screen. However if i give multiple tries of inspecting the elements by taking dumps again and again, it will give correct elements like in 4th or 5th time. 
2)Since we run all our test cases in CI (continous integration) through jenkins, when i;m executing this test in appium it always fails.

I have the latest Appium installed 1.7.1 version with Android studio installed.

Updated all my sdk manager packages to latest versions.still no resolution for this issue. we are kind of blocked with automation due to this. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can write explicit wait time until that particular element is appear